# Efficiency of DispatcherTimer versus Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

What is more efficient to use, `DispatcherTimer` or `Thread.Sleep` in C#?

I could use `DispatcherTimer`:

```
 DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
 timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
 timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
 timer.Start(); // do something every 20 seconds
```

Or, I could use `Thread.Sleep`:

```
 while(true) {
    Thread.Sleep(20000);
    // do something every 20 seconds
 }
```

In which cases should we use them? Are there any best practices?

**Edit**: Based on the first answers, I need to add that the application I am developing has no UI (so a blocking thread is no issue), as it is a background tracker, that just writes its data into a logfile.

Comment: What is your definition of "efficiency" in the context of telling a thread to do nothing for a given amount of time?

Comment: You are using a cannon to squash a mosquito.  Start with the Console Application project template.  Project + Properties, Application tab, Output type = "Windows Application" to remove the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DispatcherTimer` will invoke a method on your UI thread every N [unit of time]. `Thread.Sleep` will actually sleep the thread completely.  The difference is that with the former, the thread continues, then invokes the `Tick` event and the latter stops the Thread from doing anything.

It's important to realise that the UI Thread is busy rendering the UI and running your code; hence, a sleep in the UI thread will be perceived as an application hang.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I should have added, that there is no UI - because my application is just a tracker in the background who writes into a logfile. Then, I think, Thread.Sleep also works. But, from the answers, `DispatcherTimer` is to be preferred?

Comment: If there is no UI and your sole concern is your own code, then use the Timer class. DispatcherTimer is really for Timer ops on the UI.

Comment: Thanks, then that's what I'll do!

Answer (score 5):

If you need to operate in the dispatcher thread, then you *really* don't want to use `Thread.Sleep` - you'd end up blocking the dispatcher thread, so your user interface would be frozen.

You *could* have a background thread sleeping for 20 seconds between actions and using `Dispatcher.Invoke` to execute the action on the dispatcher thread, but that seems pretty pointless to me. `DispatcherTimer` is simpler to use than that *and* it avoids having another thread with its own dedicated stack.

Now that you've indicated that you don't actually have a UI, `DispatcherTimer` is the wrong choice as there's no dispatcher involved. I would instead use one of the other timer classes, such as [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). Using a timer indicates the intent (doing something repeatedly) more clearly than just having a separate background thread, in my view. I wouldn't worry about the *efficiency* of either solution, however.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I should have added, that there is no UI - because my application is just a tracker in the background who writes into a logfile. Then, I think, Thread.Sleep also works. But, from the answers, `DispatcherTimer` is to be preferred?

Comment: @casaout: If you don't need to be called on the dispatcher thread, I'd use a different timer, e.g. `System.Threading.Timer`. It still states your intent more clearly than using `Thread.Sleep`, IMO.

Comment: Thanks, then that's what I am going to do!

Comment: I cannot believe my advice was inline with Mr Skeet. Wow. *on my cv* :-)